# Get the data-out component vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I added a datepicker component to my vue.js project:

```
 Vue.component('d_picker', {
    data() {
        return {
          pickerOptions: {
            shortcuts: [{
              text: 'Today',
              onClick(picker) {
                picker.$emit('pick', new Date());
              }
            }, {
              text: 'Yesterday',
              onClick(picker) {
                const date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() - 3600 * 1000 * 24);
                picker.$emit('pick', date);
              }
            }, {
              text: 'A week ago',
              onClick(picker) {
                const date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() - 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 7);
                picker.$emit('pick', date);
              }
            }]
          },
          value1: '',
        };
      },
    
      template:` 
              <div>
                <div class="block">
                  
                  <el-date-picker
                      v-model="value1"
                      type="datetime"
                      placeholder="Дата и время события">
                  </el-date-picker>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            `
            })
```

I ran into a problem - updating the data in the value1 variable should entail a reactive update of the data in the variable of my main application (app.my_date), and the component sees variables only inside itself (I can't bind the target variable to v-model right away) and I don't know how do I refer to the content of a variable in a component ...

Help me, please, somehow get data from value1...

Comment: Not entirely sure what your goal is. Are you trying to emit data to the parent component or to the root? Or it this not the problem?

Comment: To the root. To variable "my_date" in my vue application "app"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways you can do exactly what you're asking for -- for example, by adding a computed property or watcher that listens for changes to value1 and emits an event that your parent component can listen on -- but I think what you're noticing here is that the d-picker component doesn't actually need any internal data. Instead, it should just be taking in a prop from above and providing a way for that prop to be changed through user input, which is exactly what the `v-model` directive can be used for.

To start with, let's re-structure your component to not have any `data` and just use props and events. Here's a simplified version that uses `input type=date` instead of your custom date picker component, but the idea is the same:

```js
Vue.component('d-picker', {
  props: ["value"],
  template: `
    <input type="date" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />
  `
})
```

Notice how the value prop is passed down directly, and we're listening on the `input` event. We're trusting that the input will emit, and in your case, that the el-date-picker will emit. Since your el-date-picker is using v-model, which as you'll see only works if the `input` event is emitted, we can assume we're good. You may need to change the event handling snippet if the payload of the event doesn't match `{target: { value: "blah" }}`.

So, when the component renders, it uses the prop passed down to it. When the user selects a date, it emits an event telling its parent that the value should change. So, our parent component needs to listen for it and respond accordingly. We can do that explicitly like so:

```js
Vue.component('app', {
    data() {
    return { my_other_field: "" }
  },
  template: `
    <div>     
      <p>The value of the date picker is: {{my_other_field}}</p>
      <d-picker :value="my_other_field" @input="my_other_field = $event"/>
    </div>
  `
})
```

This works just fine, but what we've done here is so common that it's no surprise Vue has a quicker way to do it in the `v-model` directive. `v-model` works on the default assumptions that a) the property name is "value" and b) the event emitted when it changes is `input` (those assumptions can be changed as of Vue 2.2+, fyi). So, we can rewrite the above code as:

```js
Vue.component('app', {
    data() {
    return { my_other_field: "" }
  },
  template: `
    <div>     
      <p>The value of the date picker is: {{my_other_field}}</p>
      <d-picker v-model="my_other_field" />
    </div>
  `
})
```

Hope that helps. Here's a JSFiddle with the above code demonstrated: http://jsfiddle.net/muyph790

Comment: Doesn't work... I think, it is because my tamplate is not simple datepicker, it is datepicker from that library https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/datetime-picker. I think, it has some peculiarities

Comment: @Константин - looks like Element's DatePicker emits the input event with a payload of just the new Date object, so changing the event handler to `@input="$emit('input', $event)"` inside d-picker fixes it. Here's a fiddle with that same component working: http://jsfiddle.net/4h95nc0b/